# Cygnus oauth token refresh

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus, fiware-cosmos

I'm using a cygnus build from source (latest release 0.8.2).
I've configured it to send orion subscriptions to cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org.
If I use only cosmos-user and cosmos-password it fails:

```
2015-09-06 12:21:27,063 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [ERROR - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink.process(OrionSink.java:143)] Persistence error (The /user/victor/queries/def_servpath/customer__36_productquerysalamanca directory could not be created in HDFS. HttpFS response: 503 Service unavailable)
```

So I have to use oauth-token. In this way it works successful, but my question is, **in this scenario should I refresh manually access-token and change agent.conf file?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: I saw that access-token doesn´t expire. At least after 8 hours I can use it in cygnus...so the question is:
Does access-token expire?
Reponse from cosmos-auth generator was 'expires':'3600'

Answer (score 1):

Despite the reponse message on token request says "expires: 3600" that's not true and the token has no expiration time. Why the token has no expiration time, it is something to ask to the Identity Manager (IdM) people, since the message the Token Generator for Cosmos provides is a forward of the message the IdM provides.

We have created [this issue](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/issues/491) in advance waiting the token has a real expiration time. In that case, the re-negotiation of the token will be automatically made by means of the refresh token.